# BadImageFormatException error throws while executing a console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, c#-4.0, windows-8

I'm getting below error while executing a C# console application. It's seems to me as machine specific issue. It's working on my windows 8 machine with .Net framework 4.5. But it's not working on my friend's PC with the same configuration. I have no idea how to solve this.

*I tried with changing **Visual studio** application properties - Build properties to "X86" and "Any CPU". But it's not working.*

A little help please.

```
   System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f
    5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
    File name: 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
       at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility.SetEtwProviderId()
       at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory..ctor()
       at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(Type channelType)
       at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
       at System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
       at System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateChannelFactory()
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor()
       at ApiKeyVerifier.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Projects\ApiKeyVerifier\Program.cs:line 17
    
    WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
    To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
    Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
    To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Comment: Is .Net 4.5 installed on the target PC?

Comment: @MatthewWatson : Yes. It's Windows 8. So it's by-default available.

Comment: Ah true, I was thinking of 4.5.1

Comment: So, did you "enable assembly bind failure logging"?

Comment: Turn on fusion logging.

Comment: @Will - Sorry. But I have no idea how to enable fusion logging..

Comment: use ETW to capture Fusion data: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29374658/1466046